# what is the meaning of "middle fork" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for the meaning of this sentence:
they went right, left, **middle fork**, right again.

Comment: Meaning is heavily dependent on context. Please [edit] the post to 1) describe where this sentence appears (book? newspaper? television script? what is the URL?), 2) include surrounding text or dialogue, and 3) what *you* think it might mean and what your preliminary research has found. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] if you have not done so already.

Comment: '[Take the] middle fork' means that you've reached a 4-node along a path, and you take the path that's neither the left fork nor the right fork (nor the one you've come along). The abbreviated sentence omits 'fork' after left or right (as is conventional) but wisely uses the complete term for 'middle fork'.

Comment: Think "fork in the road".

Comment: So, they went straight across, I take it. Then why not say 'straight across ' ?

Comment: @Nigel Think woods and hiking trails, not roads.  Not necessarily straight across.

Answer (score 1):

This map of [Middle Fork River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Fork_River) in Audra State Park, West Virginia, demonstrates the meaning. Going in the direction shown by my red arrow, the middle fork is the one which has been so named.

[image]

Comment: this sentence is in the first book of Harry Potter, Chapter five, page 74. they sat in a cart that was hurtling.